# SymmetricDS not syncing database with different timezone

Tags: database, synchronization, symmetricds

I set-up symmetricds ( `version 3.7.3`)  to sync a few tables from a central database to two client database, the `central` and 1 of the client(`client1`) is in same region as the central, while the other client(`client2`) is on different region. Hence, central and `client2` have different machine timezone. SymmetricDS was able to sync from `central` to `client1`, but was not able to sync from `central` to `client2`. I tried to move the database `client2` to the same region as `client1` and then it works. Is anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Which databases are used? MySql, Postgres, Oracle... What's the stack trace of the exception thrown at central and client2 databases (meaning the SymmetricDs log) when client2 is running in another time zone?

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.3.5 in amazon RDS. The `central` and `client1` database is located in `us-east` while `client2` is located in `eu-west`

Comment: Cool! What's the exception you're getting when the sync is failing?

Comment: One more thing, what's the DDL of `timestamp with time zone` columns?

Comment: There wasn't really error logs. However, In `sym_outgoing_batch` I get entries that have 'NE' status instead for `client2` while 'OK' status for `client1`. Also, the columns of the table that I have to sync, didn't really contain timestamp columns. I'm just suspecting time difference between these machine was causing symmetricds to fail.

Comment: Hm... 'NE' status means new, not error, which would be status 'ER'. Check the symmetricDs logs on the central node to see if it can access the `client2`.